# SQL Server query Where string has ':' colon in it returns not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, special-characters, varchar, sqlcommand

I am trying to query the table to look for record like this:

```
string owner = "sometextlikethis";
string pictureName = "pexels-photo.jpg_15-Apr-19 07:59:37"; //problem
PictureLibrary _pictureObj = new PictureLibrary();

var connString = db.connStringCompany;
string cmdText = "SELECT ID FROM PictureLibrary WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, PictureOwner) =@PictureOwner AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, PictureName) =@PictureName;";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection))
    {
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "@PictureOwner";
        param1.Value = owner;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
        param2.ParameterName = "@PictureName";
        param2.Value = pictureName;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read()) //record with matching owner is found but if I add pictureName as additional parameter reader does not find anything
        {
            _pictureObj.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}

return _pictureObj;
```

As I run query, the ID is null because reader does not find anything. I tried the query without pictureName parameter and it works.

I also checked the table and record where given PictureOwner and PictureName match query exists.

I am guessing I have problem with querying for record where parameter contains ':' colon. I am using filename and current date concatenating to create image name before Inserting it to SQL.

Should I change the naming of the file to avoid colon?

EDIT:

The problem was not with the colon ':' but with the length of the `VARCHAR` missing in the query.

Comment: It might have to do with the varchar lengths. Assign a proper length and prevent silent truncation.

Comment: As Luis pointed out, if you state only CONVERT(VARCHAR ...  this creates a varchar with length 1.  Try using something bigger like varchar(100)

Comment: ok, I will give it a try now

Comment: (1)What are the types of `PictureOwner` and `PictureName` in the database? Do you really need to CONVERT them? Because that prevents the query from using an indexes for them. (2) You should set the `.SqlDbType` for the parameters in the C# code.

Comment: this is how I created table: "CREATE TABLE PictureLibrary (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, PictureOwner VARCHAR(60), PictureName VARCHAR(80), PictureImage VARBINARY(MAX))";

Comment: You should ALWAYS specify length of varchar. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Yes, specifying actual length of VARCHAR worked.

Comment: @Zorkolot: just to be awfully exact: in the case of `CAST` or `CONVERT`, the default length of specifying just `VARCHAR` is **30** characters - not 1. The 1 applies to defining SQL variables or parameters (on functions and procedures) by specifying just `VARCHAR` without a specific length.

Comment: @positiveperspective The bigger problem here is that you cast for no - none, zero - reason. The column PictureOwner is defined as varchar. Casting it to varchar in the query does nothing useful and, as you have discovered, introduces a logical error. Same thing for PictureName.

Comment: I cast since I had problem with some string comparison in the past. cannot remember now, but now I do this to avoid problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here should be that you convert the `PictureOwner` to `VARCHAR`, which will truncate your string. Try to specify the corresponding length like `VARCHAR(255)`